# View man pages via Emacs in a terminal

Tags: bash, function, emacs

I can view manual page via emacs in a terminal using the following command:

`emacs -nw --eval '(progn (man "find") (delete-window))'`

Now I try to define a function in my .bashrc similar to the following:

```
function eman() { 
emacs -nw --eval '(progn (man "$1") (delete-window))';
 }
```

so that I can easily view any given man page via, e.g., `eman grep`. However, since the single quote prevents interpolation, I can not pass a command line argument to this function. How to solve this problem?

A brute-fore way is to redirect the man page to a tempoaray file and read it using emacs:

```
function eman () {
    man $1 > /tmp/$1_tmp_youjun;
    emacs -nw /tmp/$1_tmp_youjun;
}
```

but this requires an intermediate file, which seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use double quotes to enable parameters substitution, and escape internal double quotes, like this:

```sh
function eman() { 
  emacs -nw --eval "(progn (man \"$1\") (delete-window))"
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, add single quotes strategically in order to expose the $1 to the shell: `emacs -nw --eval '(progn (man "'$1'") (delete-window))';`